# Is it possible send some data with Shopify Buy Button?

Tags: shopify

Is it possible send some data (customer coment for instance) with Shopify Buy Button? Im using button o my existing web page (No online store).

Comment: where would the comment land up and also where would it impact in the backend?

Comment: It's not important where comment land up. I need option how to get customer's notes if they pressed shopify buy button. For example: customization cups, T-Shirst...

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Shopify support.

Currently with the Buy Button sales channel, you would not be able to get a customer note or comment included in the purchase. The Button allows for different variants to be chosen from a drop down menu, but not for a customer to be able to enter in information through a text box. The best alternative would be to reach out to the customer after the order is placed and get more information that way.

If you had an online store with Shopify, that is an option that you can enable, however, it's not a feature on the Buy Buttons. That being said, that would be a great improvement to our platform, and I will send that feedback along to our developers, and they can look into including it in our future :)